# How to backfill missing Date in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple table below. I am trying to count the time (in days/hours/mins/ and total hours between arrival dates and dept dates.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP 
(
    Flight_ID INT,
    Arrival_Dt DATETIME,
    Dept_DT DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO temp 
VALUES ('123', '10/14/2018 09:25 pm', '10/14/2018 11:21 pm'),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:43 pm', NULL),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:44 pm', '10/16/2018 08:04 am')
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ARRIVAL_DT,
    DEPT_DT,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60 * 60 * 24) AS D,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60 * 60) % 24 AS H,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60) % 60      AS M,
    CAST(DEPT_DT - ARRIVAL_DT AS FLOAT) * 24               AS TOTAL_HRS
FROM 
    TEMP
```

The issue I have is the `NULL` date in the `Dept_Dt` column. The date for the NULL value should be 10/14/2018 11:44 PM (one minute after 10/14/2018 11:43pm).

Currently, I am using the `GETDATE()` function to replace the null values. But doing so would inflate the time exponentially.

Here is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 
(
    ID INT,
    ARRIVAL_DT DATETIME,
    DEPT_DT DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TEMP1 
VALUES ('123', '10/14/2018 09:25 PM', '10/14/2018 11:21 PM'),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:43 PM', '09/09/2019 09:00 AM'),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:44 PM', '10/16/2018 08:04 AM')
```

As you can see, the middle record has very high in total hours (329 days, 9 hours, 17 mins, total 7905 hours)

Ideally, the accurate time is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2 
(
    ID INT,
    ARRIVAL_DT DATETIME,
    DEPT_DT DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TEMP2 
VALUES ('123', '10/14/2018 09:25 PM', '10/14/2018 11:21 PM'),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:43 PM', '10/14/2018 11:44 PM'),
       ('123', '10/14/2018 11:44 PM', '10/16/2018 08:04 AM')

SELECT
    ID,
    ARRIVAL_DT,
    DEPT_DT,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60 * 60 * 24) AS D,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60 * 60) % 24 AS H,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT) / (60) % 60      AS M,
    CAST(DEPT_DT - ARRIVAL_DT AS FLOAT) * 24               AS TOTAL_HRS
FROM 
    #TEMP2
```

Question is - is there a way to find the null values then replace its next arrival date? or some direction would be greatly appreciated. I am sorry to present a lengthy example that might have caused some confusion.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LEAD function to achieve this:

```
SELECT Flight_ID,
    Arrival_Dt,
    ISNULL(Dept_DT,LEAD(Arrival_Dt) OVER(PARTITION BY Flight_ID ORDER BY Arrival_Dt)) AS Dept_DT
FROM temp
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. It appears working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```sql
    UPDATE temp SET DEPT_DT = DATEADD(minute, 1, ARRIVAL_DT)
    WHERE DEPT_DT IS NULL
```

This sets the departure date to one minute after the arrival date in the case where the departure date is currently `NULL`.

If you are trying to just move it into `TEMP1` then:

```sql
    INSERT INTO TEMP1 (ID,  ARRIVAL_DT, DEPT_DT)
    (SELECT Flight_ID, ARRIVAL_DT,
    ISNULL(DEPT_DT, DATEADD(minute, 1, ARRIVAL_DT))
    FROM temp)
```

Comment: thank you. Just to clarify the example is 1 min. There can be days, hours, depending on the arrival date.

Comment: @joe Sorry, I didn't understand: what is the basis for if there are days, hours, minutes, etc.?

Comment: Oh, now I think I understand.. You want to replace the `NULL` with the `ARRIVAL_DT` from the next record.

Comment: So try combining the `DATEADD` with the selection of the next `ARRVIAL_DT` as shown by @PeterHe.